# foreach php html code

Tags: php, html

Im trying to populate my webpage with content from my database but i keep getting an error from this code. The error is

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ...
Code

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }


$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE 1 ORDER BY name ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

 $x = 1;
 foreach( $result as $row ): ?>



 <div class="col-sm-4">
                     <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                         <div class="single-products">
                             <div class="productinfo text-center">

                                 <img src="sample image 1" alt="" />
                                 <h2><?php echo $row['price']; ?></h2>
                                 <p><?php echo $row['detail']; ?></p>
                                 <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
                             </div>
                             <div class="product-overlay">
                                 <div class="overlay-content">
                                     <h2><?php echo $row['price']; ?></h2>
                                     <h2><?php echo $row['ID']; ?></h2>
                                     <p><?php echo $row['detail']; ?></p>
                                     <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="choose">
                             <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                                 <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>Add to wishlist</a></li>
                                 <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>Add to compare</a></li>
                             </ul>
                         </div>
                     </div>
```

Comment: try `var_dump($result)` first. is it display error or not ?

Comment: Because `$result` is not an array. Go and read, what  `mysqli::query()` returns

Comment: with var_dump($result) i get bool(false)

Comment: And what did manual say about such case?

Comment: it runs a query against the database and returns false if failure.

Comment: i thought since it was in a foreach it would just loop though the database and not need an array.

Answer (score 0):

Change `foreach( $result as $row ):` to `while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {` and Don't forget the close bracket after your html `<?php } ?>`

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }


$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE 1 ORDER BY name ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

 $x = 1;
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 ?>



 <div class="col-sm-4">
                     <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                         <div class="single-products">
                             <div class="productinfo text-center">

                                 <img src="sample image 1" alt="" />
                                 <h2><?php echo $row['price']; ?></h2>
                                 <p><?php echo $row['detail']; ?></p>
                                 <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
                             </div>
                             <div class="product-overlay">
                                 <div class="overlay-content">
                                     <h2><?php echo $row['price']; ?></h2>
                                     <h2><?php echo $row['ID']; ?></h2>
                                     <p><?php echo $row['detail']; ?></p>
                                     <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="choose">
                             <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                                 <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>Add to wishlist</a></li>
                                 <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>Add to compare</a></li>
                             </ul>
                         </div>
                     </div>
 </div>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: can you post an example i am getting some syntax errors when trying your solution.

Comment: This is what i get even after the edit- Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on boolean

Comment: `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {` try that instead of `while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {`, maybe php version does not allow `$result->fetch_object()`

Comment: After switching i get : Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: Same, you should figure that out. Read the many pages on mysqli on php.net There's loads of examples at the bottom to practice with.